# MYSQL INNER JOIN is slow with index

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing, inner-join

this is my simple inner join:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(ASSNZ.assenzeDidattiche) AS TotaleAssenze,
        SUM(ASSNZ.ore) AS totale_parziale,
        FLOOR(((SUM(ASSNZ.assenzeDidattiche) / SUM(ASSNZ.ore)) * 100)) AS andamento,
        MAX(ASSNZ.dataLezione) AS ultima_lezione,
        ASSNZ.idServizio,
        ASSNZ.idUtente
    FROM
        ciac_corsi_assenze AS ASSNZ
    INNER JOIN
        ciac_serviziAcquistati_ITA AS ACQ
               ON ACQ.idContatto = ASSNZ.idUtente
              AND ACQ.idServizio = ASSNZ.idServizio
              AND ACQ.stato_allievo <> 'ritirato'
    GROUP BY
        ASSNZ.idServizio,
        ASSNZ.idUtente
```

table "ASSNZ" has 213886 rows with index "idUtente", "idServizio"

table "ACQ" has 8950 rows with index "idContatto", "idServizio"

ASSNZ table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `ciac_corsi_assenze` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUtente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idServizio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCorso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCalendario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modalita` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assenzeDidattiche` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `assenzeAmministrative` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataLezione` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ora_inizio` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ora_fine` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataFineStage` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `giustificata` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `motivazione` longtext,
  `grouped` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idUtente` (`idUtente`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idServizio` (`idServizio`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `dataLezione` (`dataLezione`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=574582 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

ACQ table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ciac_serviziacquistati_ita` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idServizio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idContatto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idAzienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idSede` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipoPersona` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `num_registro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codice` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `dal` date NOT NULL,
  `al` date NOT NULL,
  `ore` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `costoOrario` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `annoFormativo` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `stato_attuale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datore_attuale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stato_allievo` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'corsista',
  `data_ritiro` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `crediti_formativi` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `note` longtext CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `valore_economico` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `dataInserimento` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idServizio` (`idServizio`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idAzienda` (`idAzienda`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idContatto` (`idContatto`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9542 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

this is my EXPLAIN of the select

[image]

Now because the query is slow, during 1.5s / 2.0s??

Something wrong?

**UPDATE**

added new index (with the John Bollinger's answer) to the table ciac_corsi_assenze:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dataLezione` (`dataLezione`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `test` (`idUtente`,`idServizio`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=574582 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

added new index to the table ciac_serviziAcquistati_ITA:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idAzienda` (`idAzienda`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `test2` (`idContatto`,`idServizio`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9542 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

New EXPLAIN:

[image]

But it's always slow :(

Comment: I once had this problem where the column definitions were different. The columns you are joining are `INT NOT NULL` on one table and `INT DEFAULT NULL` on another. Can you make the column definitions the same? (Of course, do it on a test table and/or db, not on live data in case something goes wrong)

Comment: @charmeleon now the columns definition are the same (INT NOT NULL). But the query it's always slow

Comment: How big is table `ciac_corsi_assenze` vs `ciac_serviziacquistati_ita`? It seems like your query basically selects every row from `ciac_corsi_assenze` (since there's no `WHERE` condition). If `ciac_serviziacquistati_ita` is significantly smaller table, you may want to "drive" the query from the smaller table first.

Comment: The plan reflecting the new indexes looks like a substantial improvement on the previous plan.  If performance is not improved, then perhaps the problem is outside the database.

Comment: I was thinking of this last night, and I think simply adding an index on `stato_allievo` will solve your problem (even if it's not a complex index)

Answer (score 0):

Your tables have *separate* indexes on various columns of interest, but MySQL will use at most one index per table to perform your query.  This particular query would probably be sped by table `ciac_corsi_assenze` having an index on `(idUtente, idServizio)` (and such an index would supersede the existing one on `(idUtente)` alone).  That should allow MySQL to avoid sorting the result rows to perform the grouping, and it will help more in performing the join than any of the existing indexes do.

The query would probably be sped further by table `ciac_serviziAcquistati_ITA` having an index on `(idContatto, idServizio)`, or even on `(idContatto, idServizio, ritirato)`.  Either of those would supersede the existing index on just `(idContatto)`.

Comment: @marcozipsp, your query isn't very complex.  If it is (now) supported by the best-suited indexes possible then the only other likely area of improvement is to beef up the hardware on which MySql is running.  Faster disk (and be sure it is *local* disk), more memory, and less contention for CPU may help.  But before considering those, do check your query plan to verify that the new indexes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

John went the right direction.  However the order of columns in the composite index needs changing.

For the `GROUP BY`, this order is needed (on `ASSNZ`):

```
INDEX(idServizio, idUtente)
```

(and that should replace `KEY(idServizio)`, but not `KEY(idUtente)`)

Then `ACQ` needs, in this order:

```
INDEX(idContatto, idServizio, stato_allievo)
```

replacing only `KEY(idContatto)`.